# not able to create table using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

Below is my code, i am trying to create table using knockout.js, but its not working. Table is not at all getting generated.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome to Collab-Todo</title>
 <meta name="layout" content="main" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h style="margin-left:px;">Welcome to Collab-Todo</h>
 <p style="margin-left:px;width:%">
 Welcome to the Collab-Todo application. This application was built
 as part of the Apress Book, "Beginning Groovy and Grails."
 Functionally, the application is a collaborative "To-Do"
 list that allows users and their buddies to jointly
 manage "To-Do" tasks.</p><br />
 <p style="margin-left:px;width:%">Building the Collab-Todo
 application is used to walk the user through using Grails . to
 build an application. Below is a list of controllers that are
 currently deployed in this application. Click on each to execute
 its default action:</p>
 <br />
 <div class="dialog" style="margin-left:px;width:%;">
 <ul>
Hi Hello Word
 </ul>
 </div>
 Test
                       <table>
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                    <th class="checkbox no-padding">
                                        <label>
                                            <input  type="checkbox"  />
                                        </label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    300
                                    </th>
                                    <!-- ko foreach: columns-->
                                    <th data-bind="attr: {id: id}">
                                        <div>
                                            <div data-bind="html:name"></div>                                           
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody >    
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>    
                    </table>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myViewModel = {
    columns:[
                {id:'title',name:'Title'},
                {id:'documentLanguage',name:'Document Language'}, 
                {id:'documentType',name:'Document Type'},
                {id:'expirationDate',name:'Expiration Date'},
                {id:'attachmentSize',name:'Attachment Size'},
                {id:'targetAccounts',name:'Target Accounts'},
                {id:'audienceType',name:'Audience Type'},
                {id:'history',name:'History'},
                {id:'action',name:'Action'}
                ]
 };
 ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
 </script>
 </html>
```

Is there anything wrong in bindings of knockout, I am trying to create the table headers using  so that it will generate a row for each row value in columns data, please help me with this

Comment: Where is the reference to knockout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add reference to the knockout.js. For example:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I included that line in the header but still its not working :(

Comment: yeah i did noticed that and i have tried with http only as  http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-debug.js     but its not working svejdar...

Comment: svejdar if i remove <meta name="layout" content="main" /> from that page, table is coming but that main layout will not be there, the result is a plain html page but the table is working fine. But i want this to work within that main layout.. any idea?